# Plot footprint instead of coordinates

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using MATLAB to print my simulation results. The results concerns a UAV's trajectory and waypoints that the UAV has to visit. The UAV is supposed to be equipped with a camera, whose range view is 10x10. Right now, the diagram shows the UAV's trajectory as a line visiting the waypoints. Is it possible, to show the camera's footprint, instead of the actual trajectory? I would like it to plot the rectangular camera's view to show the exhaustive coverage of the area. There is the option to plot the points as square, or cross, or cyrcles, but is it possible to set the boundaries of those?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using the marker size to indicate the range view is that there is no direct relation between the data units of your waypoints and the marker size. In other words, a value of `10` for the marker size doesn't necessarily mean that a side of a square marker is going to be 10 data units long (as defined by the scaling and limits of the axes).

An alternative is to plot square [patches](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) at each of your waypoints where the patch is aligned with the trajectory of the UAV. Here's how you can do this:

```
% Generate some sample data:
N = 20;                     % Number of waypoints
x = cumsum(5.*rand(1, N));  % X coordinates of UAV
y = cumsum(5.*rand(1, N));  % Y coordinates of UAV

% Compute vectors parallel and perpendicular to the trajectory at each point:
v = [diff(x); diff(y); zeros(1, N-1)];         % Vectors (1 per column)
v = bsxfun(@rdivide, v, sqrt(sum(v.^2, 1)));   % Normalize each column to a unit vector
v = v(:, [1 1:end]);                           % Replicate a vector for starting point
vCross = cross(v, [zeros(2, N); ones(1, N)]);  % Perpendicular vector

% Generate patch coordinates:
R = 10;  % Range view
xPatch = [x+(R/2).*(v(1, :)+vCross(1, :)); ...
          x+(R/2).*(v(1, :)-vCross(1, :)); ...
          x-(R/2).*(v(1, :)+vCross(1, :)); ...
          x-(R/2).*(v(1, :)-vCross(1, :))];
yPatch = [y+(R/2).*(v(2, :)+vCross(2, :)); ...
          y+(R/2).*(v(2, :)-vCross(2, :)); ...
          y-(R/2).*(v(2, :)+vCross(2, :)); ...
          y-(R/2).*(v(2, :)-vCross(2, :))];

% Plot the patches and trajectory:
patch(xPatch, yPatch, [0 0.3 0], 'FaceAlpha', 0.25, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
hold on;
plot(x, y, '-', 'Color', [0.8 0 0], 'Marker', '.', 'MarkerSize', 12);
axis equal;
```

And here's a sample plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I just did it, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As a first attempt you can specify marker shape as square and set constant marker size, e.g.

```
  plot(x,y,'s','markersize',10)
```

Here `x` and `y` are the vectors, holding the UAV coordinates. The letter 's' sets marker shape as *square*, and size is set to 10.

In reality, UAV trajectory is defined in a 3d space, where varying height above the ground corresponds to varying footprint size and shape. Taking this into account would require a bit more effort.

Also this assumes that the points are spaced closely enough otherwise there would be empty areas between markers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Your notice is correct. However, the UAV's altitude is approximately the same during the co-simulation, but what you said must be considered for future work!